# Android Download Manager can't open file even with correct MIME

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, mime, android-download-manager

I've this simple (so to speak) issue with Android's default Download Manager.

I would like to download some books (i.e. pdf, epub...) using the default Download Manager but it can't open them even if I set the correct MIME.

What I'm doing:

```
            String mime = null;
            mime = getMimeFromFilename(file.getName());
            if (mime != null) {
                Log.d("DBG", "Mime: " + mime); // When dealing with pdf it prints "Mime: application/pdf"
                request.setMimeType(mime); // I'm overwriting the content-type field and I log it so I'm SURE that the mime type is the right one!
            }
            MainActivity.downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

where getMimeFromFilename is the following:

```
public static String getMimeFromFilename(String file) {
    String mime = null;
    if (file.lastIndexOf(".") != -1) {
        String ext = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        MimeTypeMap mimetype = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        mime = mimetype.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
        // The following mime types are not included in MimeTypeMap class so i'll add them manually
        if (ext.toLowerCase(Locale.ITALY).equals("lit"))
            mime = "application/x-ms-reader";
        if (ext.toLowerCase(Locale.ITALY).equals("epub"))
            mime = "application/epub+zip";
        if (ext.toLowerCase(Locale.ITALY).equals("mobi"))
            mime = "application/x-mobipocket-ebook";
    }
    return mime;
}
```

Now, here comes the strange thing: if I open that file in this way;

```
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(PATH_TO_FILE, mime);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
```

it works as expected, while if in the Download Manager ("Download" app) I tap the downloaded file it says "Can't open file".

Moreover if I install an app like "Aldiko", if I start the intent for a PDF file it opens Aldiko and everything works; while if I tap on the file's entry inside the Download Manager it still opens Aldiko but it says "Not supported content".
With EPUB file it works well with the intent while it says "can't open file" with the download manager.

Any clues? Thanks in advance.

*********************************************EDIT:***************************************************

Things are getting really weird.

I've tried to open a pdf file through my app (intent) and through Android Download Manager ("Download" app). I've the following pdf reader installed and when I click either in my app or in the download manager on the pdf file it shows a dialog where I have to choose one of them.

```
-Adobe Reader (works through Intent & Download Manager)
-OfficeSuite  (works through Intent & Download Manager)
-PDF Reader   (works through Intent & Download Manager)
-PDF Viewer   (works through Intent & Download Manager)
-WPS Office   (works through Intent & Download Manager)
-Aldiko       (works through Intent BUT NOT THROUGH Download Manager)
-UBR          (works through Intent BUT NOT THROUGH Download Manager)
```

Looking at the logcat, I've found just this different messages using Aldiko:

-this one when it (correctly) opens the file using Intent

```
I/ActivityManager(569): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/sdcard0/MyApp/Books/mypdffile.pdf typ=application/pdf flg=0x3000000 cmp=com.aldiko.android/.ui.AliasImportActivity} from pid 8979
```

-this one when it (fails to) open the file tapping on the download manager item:

```
I/ActivityManager(569): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://downloads/all_downloads/25 typ=application/pdf flg=0x3000003 cmp=com.aldiko.android/.ui.AliasImportActivity} from pid 8979
```

Comment: call this [scanFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to see what default android scanner will return.

Comment: MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener doesn't seem to return the MIME type, am I wrong?  However I've tried with         Log.d("DBG", "MIME dal download manager: " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_MEDIA_TYPE)));
and it prints the correct Mime.

Comment: [allowScanningByMediaScanner()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#allowScanningByMediaScanner%28%29)
`If the file to be downloaded is to be scanned by MediaScanner, this
method should be called before enqueue(Request) is called.`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that method, at the moment I'm manually calling   Intent scanFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, path);   sendBroadcast(scanFileIntent);
 whenever I intercept a download finished. It doesn't resolve my problem but thank you for pointing out that method!

Comment: Does your file name have "&"?